# Unable to send Stream Object to NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, server, stream, getusermedia

I am able to access WebCam and Mic with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(), but when I send the stream object, it is empty at the server side which is running NodeJS server

**On Client Side:**

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then( (stream) => {
            video.srcObject = stream;

            socket.emit('streamVideoEvent', stream)

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
```

**On Server Side:**

```
socket.on('streamVideoEvent', (videoStream) => {

    console.log(videoStream)

    socket.emit('recieveVideoElement', videoStream)
})
```

**Log on Server Side:**

```
{}
```

Please don't answer to like to go for 'WebRTC API' and something .. I just need to send the stream to NodeJS server.

Comment: emit is a sync API, so I don't think you can just send a stream like an object reference. Did you tried `stream.pipe(socket)` ?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon can you show it with the code ...

And this I got from the client side console

[Log] TypeError: stream.pipe is not a function. (In 'stream.pipe(socket)', 'stream.pipe' is undefined) (2, line 83)

Comment: Eh sorry, but I was thinking that the stream API in the browser was like node.js. I think that this use case is interesting, I will give it a try